# IndexOutOfBoundsException when transferring a file through sockets. urgent data transfer control

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

How can I resolve this error when transferring a file through sockets:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:326)
    at Client.getFile(Client.java:18)
```

I implemented a client server application for transferring a file using the TCP protocol. Server is parallel. It is also necessary to implement transmission control using urgent data. I did not find a solution on Java on the Internet.

Class Server:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Server {
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;

    public void start(int port) throws IOException {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        while (true)
            new ClientHandler(serverSocket.accept()).start();
    }

    public void stop() throws IOException{
        serverSocket.close();
    }

    private static class ClientHandler extends Thread {
        private Socket clientSocket;
        private DataOutputStream out;
        private FileInputStream in;

        public ClientHandler(Socket socket) {
            this.clientSocket = socket;
        }

        public void run() {
            try {
                out = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
                out.writeInt((int) Prop.FILE_1.length());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                in = new FileInputStream(Prop.FILE_1);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            while (true) {
                byte buf[] = new byte[512];
                int len = 0;
                try {
                    len = in.read(buf);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if(len == -1) {
                    break;
                }
                try {
                    out.write(buf, 0, len);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    out.flush();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            /*try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                out.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                clientSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }*/

        }
    }
}
```

Class Client:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Client {
    private Socket clientSocket;
    private FileOutputStream out;
    private DataInputStream in;

    public String getFile() throws IOException {
        int i = 0;
        int len;
        byte buf[] = new byte[512];
        Integer fileSize;
        fileSize = in.readInt();
        while (i < fileSize) {
            len = in.read(buf);
            if (len == -1) {
                break;
            }
            i += len;
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
            out.flush();
        }
        out.close();
        return in.readUTF();
    }

    public void startConnection(String ip, int port) throws IOException {
        clientSocket = new Socket(ip, port);
        out = new FileOutputStream(Prop.FILE_2);
        in = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
    }

    public void stopConnection() throws IOException {
        in.close();
        out.close();
        clientSocket.close();
    }
}
```

Test

```
public class TestCS {
    @Test
            // (threadPoolSize = 3, invocationCount = 6, timeOut = 1000)
    public void givenClient1__whenServerResponds__thenCorrect() throws IOException {
        SoftAssert softAssert = new SoftAssert();
        Client client1 = new Client();
        client1.startConnection("127.0.0.1", 555);
        String file = client1.getFile();
        System.out.println(file);
        client1.stopConnection();
        softAssert.assertEquals(file, "First file!!!");
        softAssert.assertAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: `len = in.read(buf, 0, (fileSize - i < buf.length) ? fileSize - i : buf.length);` why are you doing this to yourself? Just read `buf.length` bytes. `read​(byte[] b, int off, int len)` reads *at most* `len` bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading `InputStream` wrongly. The logic you are trying to put there is already available in `DataInputStream.read(..)` method. All you have to do is to check how many bytes it read from the stream.

Change your while loop in `Client` like this

```
while (i < fileSize) {
    // javadoc for below : - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#read(byte[])
    len = in.read(buf);
    if(len<0) {
        break;
    }
    i += len;
    out.write(buf, 0, len);
    out.flush();
}
```

**Note** : I have not checked your logic. All I checked and corrected is the Exception you got.

Also, typically we do not read `fileSize` upfront. You generally keep on reading stream till you get `EOF` (-1) from the stream. Please check that logic as well.

Comment: While you're at it you may want to explain why you did that and what the problem was/how this solves it.

Comment: @Jags Yes, thanks, this solved the problem, but for some reason the client’s file is empty, nothing was written.

Comment: @Jags

The file is written only after the test is interrupted. What could be the problem?
    
Test
        public void givenClient1__whenServerResponds__thenCorrect() throws IOException {
            SoftAssert softAssert = new SoftAssert();
            Client client1 = new Client();
            client1.startConnection("127.0.0.1", 555);
            String file = client1.getFile();
            System.out.println(file);
            client1.stopConnection();
            softAssert.assertEquals(file, "First file!!!");
            softAssert.assertAll();
        }

Comment: @АлександрШафаренко I do not know how exactly you are using Client class. So impossible to find the problem.

Comment: @Jags I updated the post with the modified code so you can help me

Comment: @АлександрШафаренко your question is now different from the original one. This answer solved the problem you originally had, so please mark this as the correct answer and open a different question. Thank you.